# URL with choice name folder

Tags: javascript, excel, url, servicenow

I would like to know if it is possible to define a filename through a URL.

```
var url = "myurl"
g_navigation.openPopup(url);
```

these two lines allow me to upload an excel file but not to define a name to my file. do you know how to define a name by passing through a URL

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At this time there is no way to pass a file name as a param when exporting table data via URL.

Reference: https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/rome-platform-administration/page/administer/exporting-data/task/t_ExportDirectlyFromTheURL.html